# How to Hide Blog Post Author?

Tags: themes, css, author, blog

On the post archive page [here](http://staceyrosscohen.com/news-and-insights/)

And individual post pages, like [this](http://staceyrosscohen.com/outdoor-voices-ceo-tyler-haney-makes-noise-in-the-activewear-industry/)

I'd like to hide the author, which currently says "by coadmin", but no plug-ins i've tried work, and I can't find any CSS lines referring to the author specifically. I can hide all the info by targeting .post-info {display: none} but I only want the author hidden.

If I target the specific div of the author name I can hide it, like:

```
#rd_tebhz4xe9fvnw90a41ec > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.post-info > a:nth-child(1) {
display: none;}
```

But that leaves "by" still there.

Does anyone have any suggestions? The Wordpress theme is called "The Fox".

Comment: Please show the code for your theme on this page. Can't tell based on this information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not positive how to show it to you though?

Comment: Most suitable approach would be to create a child theme and remove the author information for these two pages.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use Firebug in Firefox to see the CSS class used for the author name, then disable display.

So, assuming that the css class was called 'author_name', I would put this in the styles.css of the child theme that I was using, or in the 'extra CSS' area of the theme settings (if available);

`.author_name {display:none !important;}`

That will hide the author name.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that in Google Chrome Inspect (is it the same as firebug?) but the only CSS class I can find is ".post-info", which if I disable, hides all the info, when I only want the author hidden.

Comment: In that case, it appears that your theme does not specify a CSS class for the author (byline). 

So, assuming you want to keep the theme, you would create a Child Theme (because you don't want to modify theme code) and use a modified version of the theme's page.php file that removes the code for the byline. (as mentioned by "M-R" in a comment on your question.

Themes can handle the byline info differently, so your ultimate solution is really theme-dependent.